# C++ Win32 GDI+ drawstring from wchar_t*

Tags: c++, winapi

I've done searching and spent at least an hour on this.

```
wchar_t* fooBar = (wchar_t*)L"BlahBlah\0";
//GetWindowText(pDIS->hwndItem, (wchar_t*)fooBar, 64); 
g->DrawString(fooBar, -1, &font, rectf, &strFormat, textColorUp);
```

That works, and compiles; as is the string is drawn correctly "BlahBlah."

The problem is that I want to use the value of GetWindowText() that I have commented it out.

It is likely problem converting, but I just can't find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to allocate space for the `GetWindowText` function to write to. You can't provide the address of a string literal since those are not modifiable.

```
wchar_t buffer[1024];
GetWindowText(pDIS->hwndItem, buffer, _countof(buffer));
g->DrawString(fooBar, -1, &font, rectf, &strFormat, textColorUp);
```

Comment: Thanks. I found the macro for _countof(), and that is:

#define _countof(array) (sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]))

Comment: @EvanCarslake Unless you want to be limited to a fixed maximum length, you can call `GetWindowTextLength` first, and then allocate a dynamic buffer.